# Is there a way to shield the fluidics of a solenoid valve from its magnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetism, solenoid, magnetics, solenoid-valve, magnetic-flux

Are there any solenoid valves on the market that specifically shield the fluidics from the magnetic field of the solenoid actuation? Either by physically redirecting the fluidics around the coils or maybe by shunting the field through mu-metal casing?

Also: If I were to transport ferromagnetic particles through a typical solenoid valve, is the magnetic field powerful enough (in a typical valve) to effect it, anyway? Should I even be concerned?

Comment: Make magnetism your friend and activate the magnetic field to stop the movement of the ferromagnetic particles. Who needs a solenoid valve if you do this!!

Comment: That would be ideal, but I'm building a system that records audio to ferromagnetic particles suspended in oil. So, activating the magnetic field would erase or otherwise modify the audio stream. I've considered systems that use momentary actuation to create or stop momentum in the fluid similar to how you describe, but that would leave gaps in the audio. Using discrete solenoid "steps" is a better way to get the fluid around.

Comment: Now that sounds really cool so please explain more.

Comment: Sounds cool and a little bizarre... however distancing the mechanics from the coil can be done with a push rod or similar could work... it will probably mean customizing the valve solenoid assembly.

Comment: Custom solenoids were also my conclusion, but those would be my last option after exhausting everything else.

I understand there are also servo-controlled valves that may be a better option all around, but more expensive and bulky. I'm leaning towards servos, but I still need to compare data. PSI/flow control is attractive, but I also want the tight response times found in solenoids.

Comment: Servos aren't going to work for me. Looks like the best way to learn is by doing some prototyping. These are the solenoids I have in mind: [link](http://www.aliexpress.com/item/Hot-Electric-Solenoid-Valve-Magnetic-DC-12V-N-C-Water-Air-Inlet-Flow-Switch-1-2/32262499123.html?spm=2114.01020208.3.2.HWRSIt&ws_ab_test=201526_1,201527_4_71_72_73_74_75,201409_4) accepting other recommendations, though.